What's the difference between repeats and loops in %timeit?
The %timeit magic in IPython provides a convenient shorthand for benchmarking performance. According to the docs, it provides the following options:
-n: execute the given statement  times in a loop. If  is not provided,  is determined so as to get sufficient accuracy.
-r: number of repeats , each consisting of  loops, and take the average result. Default: 7
Besides the difference in default behavior, what is the difference between these two options? How does it behave differently from just looping × times through the code? What differences should I expect between setting -n and setting -r?
The docs for the magic and module may be relevant. This StackOverflow question doesn't provide enough detail to answer my question.
